# Layer Order in Pop-up information - ArcGIS Online

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, popup, display, order

Is there a way that I can choose the priority on how the pop-up window shows on ArcGIS Online?

For example, I have 2 layers named Active Country and Inactive Country. In my current data, I have 2 Nigeria polygons wherein each represent a program.

What I want to happen is to decide the pop-up display order of overlapped polygons.

Answer (score 1):

The popups are returned by what is returned by the server first, there is no prioritizing of results.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there's a way on how I can make a certain feature to appear first.

Answer (score 0):

Esri has a resource page to assist you with configuring the pop up in ArcGIS Online [Configure pop-ups](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/configure-pop-ups.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_0505720B006E43C5B14837A353FFF9EC)

> Browse to the sublayer that contains the feature data you want to configure in a pop-up, click More Options More Options, and click Configure Pop-up.

Also, [View pop-ups](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/get-started/view-pop-ups.htm)

> A list of field attributes shows typical name/value identify results. Authors can modify the visibility, order, number formatting, and date formatting so the information appears in a logical and understandable format.

Comment: Thank you for this but what I meant is for the data to appear in a preferred format when two data overlap each other.